# What is the cause of "Syntax error, insert "Finally" to complete TryStatement"

Tags: java, try-catch

I'm using eclipse to create an android application that gets a list of all the currently displayed apps on the phone but I am getting an error that I've never seen before. My code looks right but at one of the "}" brackets im getting the error "Syntax error, insert "Finally" to complete TryStatement", does anyone know how to solve this error?

Thank you.

Comment: This is a java question and has little to do with Android.

Comment: We need code to help anyway. But I agree with rogerkk, this is not Android specific.

Comment: If this is anything like JSPs, make sure any embedded snippets of code are fully closed. I've run into similar problems working in old JSP code where the HTML had open tags but no close tags.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to either have a "catch" clause or a "finally" to accompany your try:

```
try {
    // ... something dangerous ...
} catch(IOException e) {
    // ... handle errors ...
} finally {
    // ... cleanup that will execute whether or not an error occurred ...
}
```

Comment: thank you Matthew, i actually had that down alright but i had a try statement within a try statement and i only had the catch(IOException e) {
    // ... handle errors ...
} finally {
    // ... cleanup that will execute whether or not an error occurred ...
}
Down for the 1st one and not the 2nd try, that why i was getting the error